# Download, unzip, import API JSON zip file from website

Tags: r

I am trying to read a file from website: https://seasonaljobs.dol.gov/feeds

The file I want is a json zipped file: https://api.seasonaljobs.dol.gov/datahub-search/sjCaseData/zip/jo/2023-12-29

I have tried various methods to unzip a file and download it but none have worked for me.

Can you please help me?

[image]

This is the latest version of my attempts

```
temp <- tempfile()
download.file("https://api.seasonaljobs.dol.gov/datahub-search/sjCaseData/zip/jo/2023-12-25.zip",temp)
data <- read.table(unz(temp, "a1.dat"))
unlink(temp)
```

This is the error message:

```
> temp <- tempfile()
> download.file("https://api.seasonaljobs.dol.gov/datahub-search/sjCaseData/zip/jo/2023-12-25.zip",temp)
trying URL 'https://api.seasonaljobs.dol.gov/datahub-search/sjCaseData/zip/jo/2023-12-25.zip'
downloaded 55 KB

> data <- read.table(unz(temp, "a1.dat"))
Error in open.connection(file, "rt") : cannot open the connection
In addition: Warning message:
In open.connection(file, "rt") :
  cannot open zip file 'C:\Users\AppData\Local\Temp\RtmpMT9ToE\file4e387cdd2f0d'
```

I want to download all the fields for a specific state (for example: `"CA"`)

Comment: _Look at the file_. For me, the allegedly-`zip` file starts with `<!DOCTYPE html><html lang="en"><head>`, meaning it is not in fact a zip file. If you take that same URL and try to look at it in a regular web browser, you'll see that it opens up a normal-looking web page. If you look at the browser's network trace (under its devtools) while loading, you'll see that the first response is `HTTP 302`, meaning that *"the resource requested has been temporarily moved to the URL given by the Location header"* (from https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Status/302).

Comment: I don't trust "302" to truly mean "temporarily moved", to be honest. I've done no digging into that website's API policies, so you may find there what is required for this connection (perhaps it truly has changed). It can easily be: (1) they have completely changed the tier for API access, you need to find updated docs to update your methods; (2) perhaps geo-ip blocking, are you looking from outside the USA? Or (3) auth is required, and they silently redirect; this is sloppy, in my book, and the most unlikely of my three thoughts. Good luck!

Comment: Your first link doesn't have the `.zip` file extension, so I tried that too ... and while it starts with `HTTP 200` (good), the download fails for some other reason. So I tried chopping everything off and go to just the URL, it takes me to a login page. My _guess_, at this point, is that the `HTTP 302` should really be `HTTP 403` ("forbidden", meaning you need to authenticate). This to me means you need to use your credentials, and something like the `httr` package to retrieve your data.

Comment: Oddly enough I can get 2 first application feeds through US-based proxy, for the 3rd one (9142B) direct download is also working.  When you manage to get those files, `read.table()` isn't much of a help here as zip contains JSON. Though `df <- unz("2023-12-29_jo.zip", "2023-12-29_jo.json") |> jsonlite::parse_json(simplifyVector = T)` works. Aslo, the 790/790A feed zip is 17+MB,  your downloaded 55 KB is clear indicator that there's something wrong with the file.